# Angular: dependency injection not happening properly if we place .js or .ts at the end of import statement

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-di

A typical import statement goes like this:

```
import {HelpService} from '../../help.service'
```

If I autowire `HelpService` in the constructor, I get an existing instance of `HelpService`. However, if I import it like this:

```
import {HelpService} from '../../help.service.js'
```

Now, I receive a brand new instance of the service instead of an existing one. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a really cool feature of Typescript, detailed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

It essentially alleviates the need for a developer to specify the type of file, because *Typescript compiles down to Javascript,* and the fact that a developer can reference a module in many ways (with .ts, .tsx, .js, etc)

Comment: But why do we receive a brand new instance while autowiring in the second case, but an existing one in the first case?

Comment: @Daud - what you are stating is not possible give the code your question. Please create a [example] that demonstrates the difference.

Comment: @Daud this may be due to the module resolution strategy, mentioned in the link posted. If you specify `.js` - it will try to interpret it as a `Node.js` module, however with the others, a `Classic` or plain Typescript module (which technically still needs to be compiled). Does that somewhat answer your question?

Comment: @jarodsmk The interpretation as Node.js module makes sense. If you can update the answer with some documentation, it'll be great. Can't think of a way to replicate this on StackBlitz without resorting to routing or I would have :(